# How to turn off all collisions?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using Gazebo 2.2.3 under ROS Indigo.  I am wondering how I can turn off collision on all models (or even one at a time) without turning off the physics.  I need the sensor data from the physics but I also want the models to pass through each other if they come into contact.

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17216/how-to-turn-off-all-collisions?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3069/pi-robot/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can try using the `<collide_without_contact>` tag. [Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arpg/Gazebo/master/test/worlds/collide_without_contact.world)'s a nice example world.

You could also look at [collide bitmasks](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=collide_bitmask&cat=physics), in case you still want some models to collide with each other.

(by the way, Gazebo 2 is not supported anymore, it's recommended you move to Gazebo 7)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3069/pi-robot/) on 2017-09-10**:
Thanks!  That did the trick.  And yeah, I've run Gazebo 7 on some of my Ubuntu 14.04 machines and ROS Indigo but 2.2.3 is running fine for what I need right now.